# Create a complete 10.5 font size setup for XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontsize

I must print a book with 10.5 pt size, and I am using XeLaTeX because I need to use some otf fonts.

In the past, I have been able to create a custom fontsize by redefining the commands `\normalsize`, `\small` etc., where I also redefined the baseline and display skips, which I also need to do in this occasion.

I am new to XeLaTeX and I don't know how to proceed. For example, which command am I supposed to use to substitute for `\@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}`?

Comment: the command you show sets 12pt on 14.5pt so just change it to `{10.5}{13}` or whatever size you want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `fontsize` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontsize}
\changefontsize[12.4]{10.5}
%#1: \baselineskip
%#2: \normalsize

\begin{document}

Hello World!    

% This is to test the settings      
\printsamples{12.4}{10.5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard `CMR` family, then please follow the below tags:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{10.5}{12}%
   \abovedisplayskip 12\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@%
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip%
   \let\@listi\@listI}%
\normalsize%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```