# Minion Pro Regular 13.5pt

Tags: minionpro

I am trying to use Minion Pro Regular with overleaf. I've managed to get it installed, butI have the impression that the only font sizes available are 10pt, 11pt and 12pt. I am supposed to use 13.5pt. If that is absolutely impossible, I may get away with 13pt or 14pt.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576929 ?

Comment: minion pro is a single font which can be sclaed to any size. unlike computer modern there are not separate fonts at different design sizes. So you can use whatever size you like.  If you showed what you did and what error you got someone could help.

Comment: Thanks! I managed, but as a result I discovered a more fundamental problem. I will raise that in a new question.